# how to separate the output given below

Tags: php

530b214119510

```
    <div class="Mcontainer">
    <div class="MprojectH"><b>HEADLINE 1</b></div>

    <div class="MprojectC">
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>one</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

<div class="MprojectL"><a href="">Click here</a></div>
</div>
```

**above is output of `$value`**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['partner_1'])) {

                if (!empty($_POST['editor1'])) 
{
    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value )
    {
        if ( ( !is_string($value) && !is_numeric($value) ) || !is_string($key) )
            continue;

        if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ){
            $value = htmlspecialchars( stripslashes((string)$value) );
        } else {
            $value = htmlspecialchars( (string)$value );
        }
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($value);
            echo "</pre>";
}   }   
}
?>
```

Now I want to insert the above value in the db but the problem is that I have different columns for **530b214119510**    and **div....** . `$value` has all the value , its not in the 
array . So how to separate the value without disturbing the html content and id.

Comment: 530b214119510 means what?

Comment: @PHP_USER1 is 530b214119510 in the html code ?

Comment: @Tabby I am using foreach for all the post , so I am getting two values from my form ie uniq_id and htlm content

Comment: how does `$value` prints that string ?

Comment: @PHP_USER1 how did the uniq_id generate ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
    if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ){
        array_push($value, htmlspecialchars( stripslashes((string)$value) ));
    } else {
        array_push($value, htmlspecialchars( (string)$value ));
    }
```

instead of

```
    if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ){
        $value = htmlspecialchars( stripslashes((string)$value) );
    } else {
        $value = htmlspecialchars( (string)$value );
    }
```

Comment: Note that if you answer such questions, which doesn't fit the quality standards, you support them.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in D:\xampp\htdocs\relg_n2\admin\check2.php on line 17    and   my line 17 is $value[] = htmlspecialchars( (string)$value );

Comment: I modified my answer :)

Comment: No i can't use it , 
Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\relg_n2\admin\check2.php on line 17

HEADLINE 1




 
one

 
one

 
one

 
one




Click here



Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in D:\xampp\htdocs\relg_n2\admin\check2.php on line 17
SUBMIT

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/preg_match) to extract the value from the html and store it in another variable. You can also use [DOMDOCUMENT](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to extract the value from the html code. These methods wont alter you html code.

Comment: please can you tell how to do it